# Android custom dialog not displayed

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I would like to notify user as soon as they receive a message by displaying custom dialog. I have a custom layout for the dialog box and referenced it as such:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dia = builder.create();
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity.this); //builder = alertbuilder object
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            builder.setView(dialoglayout);
            builder.setTitle("REQUEST");
            builder.setMessage("Would you like to accept it?");
            //builder.show();
            dia.show(); //dia = dialog object

            spRequest.play(spSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        dia.cancel();

                    }
                }, 7000);
```

I would like to play a sound pool and display the dialog for 7 minutes and stop. But the soundpool plays but not the dialog, instead the screen is dark for 7 minutes. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I was creating dialog with empty builder. The order is the builder object should be stuffed with the custom layout and all stuff you want before you assign it to the dialog object, otherwise the dialog will show but it will be blank. Here is the correct code for anyone suffering like I did :)

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            builder.setView(dialoglayout);
            builder.setTitle("REQUEST");
            builder.setMessage("Would you like to accept?");
            dia = builder.create();
            //builder.show();
            dia.show();

            spRequest.play(spSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1);
               new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       dia.dismiss();
                   }
               }, 7000);    //the alert will play for 7 seconds and stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am a beginner but I think you niss one Command in the LayoutInflater line.
try to add  getActivity()  it need to look like this.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

i hope that i helped you.

Comment: @Riosh, you use getActivity() method when you are in FragmentActivity. I am in Activity so no need for that. Thanks for your help though:)